# How to develop app using codename one without GUI builder?

Tags: codenameone, xlet

1. Using GUI Builder is helpful

   - but the limitation is there.
   - so I want to develop application using Java programming only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 1):

Just select the hand coded application in the new project wizard. With the recent version of the plugin this is now the default.